# I want to use WebView2 on Windows Forms for automatic login, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, webview2

[This is the website I want to test](https://grabcad.com/login)

this is my code

```
webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("javascript:(function() {  document.getElementsByName('member[email]')[0].value = 'MyUsername@gmail.com';document.getElementsByName('member[password]')[0].value = 'MyPassword'; })()");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.864.35#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_ExecuteScriptAsync_System_String_) to run script rather than navigating to a javascript URI. You can open DevTools to watch for any errors that your script might generate.

```
webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() {  document.getElementsByName('member[email]')[0].value = 'MyUsername@gmail.com';document.getElementsByName('member[password]')[0].value = 'MyPassword'; })()");
```

Comment: Thanks @David Risney. I tried your method it works for fill user pass on username and password box,but it not works after I click login, my username and password are blank.
can you suggest me what might be causing this?
I'm new to javascript.

Comment: You probably need to go deeper in your hosted page, perhaps the server side code is looking at some hidden fields.....